# Remapped Ctrl+V jumps to to new line in some apps, Ctrl+A moves cursor to the start of line (text areas)

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I configured general "Edit" shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, etc. shortcuts in "Linux/Windows" style trough **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App shortcuts > All Applications** like so:

[image]

I also swapped Mac's <kbd>Fn</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in "Modifier keys" and physical keys on keyboard.
Running on Monterey 12.1 MacBook Pro M1

[image]

In some applications like Notes, Pages, Terminal, Telegram, Intelij IDEA it works as expected. But in some apps like Slack, RDM, and Chrome in some cases it works weird.

Most annoying is jumping to the end of the text area after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> somewhere inside the text while editing the text area. The first press of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> jumps to the end of the text area, a second press of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> will paste the text. Such behaviour repeats in Slack and Chrome text areas (in Chrome's address bar works fine).

Another annoying bug is sometimes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> moves cursor to the start of the line instead of "Select All". Mostly repeats also in text areas of different apps (Slack, Chrome, Postman).

Looks like Mac has it own shortcuts for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> specifically for text areas. I want to learn how to find them and disable/reassign.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem and I think [this](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4138#issuecomment-642584355) answers your question and it worked for me. To be more specific, you need to mask ctrl +v by default.

```
$ mkdir ~/Library/KeyBindings/
$ vi ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
{
   "^v" = "noop:";
}
```

Comment: worked for me, but dont forget to logout+login, or restart system.

Comment: one more question, what if I want to disable more shortcuts like ^a and ^z?

Comment: This works for me on most apps, but not Jupyter Notebook. In Jupyter Notebook `ctrl-v` still jumps to paragraph end. I just figured out a simple solution and posted here https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4138#issuecomment-1636879969